# How to install virtualbox-6.0.14-dfsg/src/VBox/Additions/x11/x11stubs

Tags: virtualbox, compiling

On one of my Ubuntu 19.10 machines my install of VBox from the repository is fatally unstable -- freezes my machine with mysterious errors that has no takers on any of the forums I've posted to. So I'm trying a local build of VirtualBox.

After a successful configure of the `apt source` I go to build using `kmk` which fails with the error in the subject line of this question.

I am attempting to fix this by installing x11 libraries for VBox but run into the issue below.

What is the fix for this?

```
 kmk all
 /hd2/projects/virtualbox-6.0.14-dfsg/src/VBox/Additions/x11/Makefile.kmk:34: /hd2/projects/virtualbox-6.0.14-dfsg/src/VBox/Additions/x11/x11stubs/Makefile.kmk: No such file or directory
 kmk: *** No rule to make target '/hd2/projects/virtualbox-6.0.14-dfsg/src/VBox/Additions/x11/x11stubs/Makefile.kmk
```

`apt search for virtualbox x11` gives :

```
  virtualbox-guest-x11 - x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
  virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe - x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
```

However when I try to install `virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe` I get a full color warning popup :

```
              You are running a kernel (version 5.3.0-19-generic) and attempting to remove the same version.                             │ 
            │                                                                                                                            │ 
            │ This can make the system unbootable as it will remove /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-19-generic and all modules under the directory   │ 
            │ /lib/modules/5.3.0-19-generic. This can only be fixed with a copy of the kernel image and the corresponding modules.       │ 
            │                                                                                                                            │ 
            │ It is highly recommended to abort the kernel removal unless you are prepared to fix the system after removal.              │ 
            │                                                                                                                            │ 
            │ Abort kernel removal?                                                                                                      │ 
            │                                                                                                                            │ 
            │
```

Comment: This happens all the time with VB when you're trying to install it with the latest-and-greatest kernel. Check out this post from one of the VB forums moderator: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=95398#p461835

Comment: @ajgringo619 The strange thing is that it is working fine on my other 19.10 machines. This particular machine is a dark child and I often find I have better results with local builds. So -- I would like to make this build, but I may have to wait I suppose. Thank you.